# Problem with `git instaweb` on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed: No such projects found

Tags: git, lighttpd, gitweb, apparmor

I am having trouble setting up git instaweb on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

I did install `git-web` and `lighttpd`.

When I do `git instaweb` in the root of my git project, the browser opens in a page that says `No such projects found`.

I tryed to put the project root in `/srv/git` but it also did not work.

This should be as simple as doing these commands in the project root:

```bash
git instaweb
```

and

```bash
git instaweb --stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, I have noticed that the command `git instaweb` creates a folder under `.git` called `gitweb`. In this folder we can find a configuration file for `lighttpd` called `lighttpd.conf` and another for `gitweb.cgi` called `gitweb_config.perl`.

Assuming you are in the root of the project, it is possible to run `lighttpd` "by hand" like this:

```bash
lighttpd -D -f .git/gitweb/lighttpd.conf
```

- `-f` specifies the `lighttpd` configuration file.
- `-D` tells `lighttpd` not to daemonize.

When I access the browser page, I get on the console:

```bash
[Fri Jan  5 17:51:35 2024] gitweb.cgi: Can't exec "/usr/bin/git": Permission denied at /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi line 3335.
```

It seems to be a problem with `/usr/bin/git`. I tried to add the following line to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.share.git-web.gitweb.cgi`:

```
/usr/bin/git rix,
```

But it still did not work. After some searching I found a way to debug `AppArmor`:

```bash
grep -i apparmor\=\"DENIED\" /var/log/audit/audit.log | less
...
type=AVC msg=audit(1704485570.756:138288): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" class="file" profile="gitweb.cgi" name="/usr/libexec/git/git" pid=31445 comm="gitweb.cgi" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

So I deleted the previously added line to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.share.git-web.gitweb.cgi` and added the following line:

```
/usr/libexec/git/git rix,
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: Please mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: I can only accept it in 48 hours. There are still 19 to go.